# Cauchy Product of two Taylor Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, cauchy-product

I'm probably being a bit stupid here but I've been assigned this question and don't really know where to go with it.

*Compute the first 5 terms of the Cauchy product of the Taylor Series for $(1-x)^{2/5}$ and $(1-x)^{3/5}$.*

I've calculated the first five terms of the respective Taylor Series as

$$(1-x)^{2/5}= 1 - \frac{2x}{5} - \frac{3x^2}{25}- \frac{8x^3}{125}-\frac{26x^4}{625}$$

and

$$(1-x)^{3/5} = 1- \frac{3x}{5} - \frac{3x^2}{25} - \frac{7x^3}{125} - \frac{21x^4}{625}$$

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help me proceed with what to do next.

Comment: what does the subscript $5$ mean in $(1 - x)_5^2$?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now. I mean to say $(1-x)$ to the power of $2/5$ but I'm having some issues with the formatting.

Comment: @Bernard  You're right.  I missed the most recent comment.

Comment: Just follow the definition of Cauchy product of series. If $\sum c_n x^n$ is the Cauchy product of $\sum a_n x^n$ and $\sum b_n x^n$, then $c_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k b_{n - k}, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

Comment: Well: do what is asked: the Cauchy product. Don't forget to truncate terms of degree $\ge 5$. You should find $1-x$, naturally.

Comment: The problem I have is more applying the cauchy product in this context. I'd just basically like to see how I'm supposed to start it off, I'm sure I'll be able to finish it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safety, you can display the Cauchy product as an ordinary hand-made multiplication for numbers, truncating at order $5$. Here is an example of how to begin:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, figured out no problem. As I said, I was being a bit stupid haha. Thank you very much!